# React Native - How to change tabs from when you are in a Stack Screen from a different tab?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Lets say I'm in the home tab and in the home tab it displays the user's profile picture. If the user clicks on their profile picture, I want them to be navigated to the settings tab. How can I do this in React Native?
I am currently using @react-navigation/bottom-tabs for the tabs.

Comment: share you code here

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Image` in `TouchableOpacity` :

```
onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('settingTab'); }}
```

Comment: thanks that works. I have a follow up question. Lets say in the settingTab I have multiple Screens in the stack. Is it possible to navigate to the settingTab and to a specific Screen? Instead of going to the first screen in the settingTab

Comment: for that, you have to add conditions using params